# AutoHotKey: Toggle RAlt to Mouse Hotkey with Another Hotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, keymapping

I'm trying to create a Hotkey (Win+Shift+Q) that toggles on/off another Hotkey that changes the right Alt key to a left mouse click; however, I can't get it to work.

Expected Behavior:

1. Pressing Windows+Shift+Q will initially toggle the Right-Alt key to act as a left mouse click.
2. Pressing Windows+Shift+Q again will toggle the Right-Alt key back to acting as a Right-Alt key.
3. Pressing Windows+Shift+Q again will revert to the left-click behavior (see #1).  And so on.

Here's the most current iteration of my code:

```
Hotkey, RAlt, MyClick, On
#+Q::   ;Win+Shift+Q :: ::Right-Alt acts as a left mouse button click
    switch := !switch
    MsgBox %switch%
    Hotkey RAlt, % (switch ? "Off": "On")
    Return

MyClick:
    MouseClick
Return
```

When I run my script I get the following error after clicking OK on the MsgBox and the script quits:

```
Error: Nonexistent hotkey

Specifically: RAlt

    Line#
    141: Hotkey,RAlt,MyClick,On
    143: switch:=!switch
    144: MsgBox %switch%
 -->145: Hotkey RAlt, % (switch ? "Off": "On")
    146: Return
    149: MouseClick
    150: Return

 The current thread will exit.
```

Most of the other posts that might relate ([Can AutoHotKey toggle keymapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506736/can-autohotkey-toggle-keymapping), [Autohotkey: Toggle a set of keybinds on and off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315817/autohotkey-toggle-a-set-of-keybinds-on-and-off)) only deal with key to key mapping and not key to mouse mapping.  I can't tell if that is the cause of my issues or not.

Previously I had this, but the Win+Shift+Q didn't toggle the behavior, RAlt always acted as a left-click so I commented it out:

```
#+Q::   ;Win+Shift+Q :: ::Right-Alt acts as a left mouse button click
    RAlt::LButton
    ;Hotkey, RAlt, Toggle ;Does not work for some reason

    int += 1
    test := mod(int, 2) = 0
    if (test) {
        msgbox on
        Hotkey, RAlt, On
    }
    else {
        msgbox off
        Hotkey, leftClick, Off
    }
Return
```

I'll also add that I would like this behavior across Windows, not just a single application (which also seems to be a topic in other posts that allows for the #IfWinActive-type suggestions/solutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your current iteration of code in AutoHotkey v1.1.13.01 Unicode 32-bit and I don't have any errors after pressing `OK` on the message box, the script works as advertised.

Try updating your AutoHotkey version here: http://ahkscript.org/download/ and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Not sure why my older version wasn't working.  I also had to move my initial Hotkey (Hotkey, RAlt, MyClick, On) to the top of my file otherwise I'd keep getting the error (that might have fixed it in the older version too, I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

```
bState:=False

#If bState
   RAlt::Click
#If

#+vk51:: ; win + shift + q
   KeyWait, vk51
   TrayTip, % "state of switch", % (bState:=!bState) ? "on":"off"
   Return
```